# Pandas - Can't Match Strings that contain a **

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I know this is probably a bad practice, but the company I work for will store organizations name that holds special info in the title with a ** and its causing me plenty of headaches.  Still learning the ropes of python and would love some clarification and some assistance:

First, intro to what I am trying to do.

I have a database of records that I need to assign out to separate members of a team who own an organization.  Sadly, our systems are being reworked and this report is considered "legacy" so I am forced to do this outside of our system.

The data is incoming looking as such:

```
Case Reason Referral Partners
Case reason 1   Org 1
Case reason 1   Org 2363
Case reason 8   Org 53
Case reason 4   Org 100
Case reason 3   org 68
Case reason 2   Org 100
```

I keep workers with their assigned orgs in one dictionary, and a dictionary of workers with their ID to have the program auto assign it in our CRM such as

```
org_owners = {'Worker 1': ['Org 1', 'Org 2']}
user_id = {'Worker 1' : 'ID 1'}
```

and my code that runs it through looks as such:

```
for i in user_id:
    list_of_values = hospital_owners[i]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if row['Referral Partners'] in (list_of_values):
            print(user_id[i])
            row['User Id'] = user_id[i]
        else:
            pass
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testoutput.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

which produces my desired outcome of:

```
Case Reason      Referral Partners    Owner ID
Case Reason 1    Org 1                ID1
Case Reason 1    Org 2363             ID13
```

Super simple code, I am sure its not the fastest and any advice I am always willing to take and learn from.  My problem is that it assigns every single org correctly expect ones that would look as:

```
org1**Partner Handles X Type of Case
```

and anything with ** wont match up.  How do I get around this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide an example of a problematic dataframe as well?

Comment: @fuglede It isn't so much the dataframe that is the problem, its the CRM we use, my IT team is not able to update relationships at a healthy rate for the thousands of records we assign a day, so they assign entirely to me, and I export a report via CSV and then import it and match it based on dictionaries I set as above.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pandas can replace most of the code here.

```
import pandas as pd
```

First, we'll build a dataframe that approximates what is coming from your CRM.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Case Reason':['Case reason 1','Case reason 1','Case reason 8','Case reason 4'],
               'Referral Partners':['Org 1','Org 2363','Org 1**Partners','Org 100']})

    Case Reason     Referral Partners
0   Case reason 1   Org 1
1   Case reason 1   Org 2363
2   Case reason 8   Org 1**Partners
3   Case reason 4   Org 100
```

If the data from your CRM is in a flat file, you can use [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to load it into a dataframe. Once you have done so, you can take advantage of the speed of pandas to perform the operations on the resulting dataframe that you were accomplishing before with your for loop.

Next, I'm seeing that you have two dictionaries; one linking Orgs to Workers, and another linking Workers to Worker IDs. If possible, it may be helpful to simplify this by building a dictionary that has Orgs as keys, and Worker IDs as items, like the following.

```
org_owners = {'Org 1':'ID 1','Org 2':'ID 1'}
```

This makes it a little easier to use the pandas map function to recode the keys in this dictionary to the corresponding items. However, if you still need the Worker numbers (e.g., 'Worker 1'), you could use the process below to recode from Org to Worker number, then from Worker number to Worker ID, instead of the reconfigured dictionary above. There's surely a better way to accomplish that piece, but that's all that's coming to mind for me.

The line below creates a new column with the Owner ID in it. Using pandas [extract string method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) we can use a regular expression to find any string in the Referral Partners column that begins with 'Org' followed by a single whitespace (\W) and at least one number (\d{1,}). This will allow us to ignore the double asterisks and other text that is appearing in the cells. Next, the [map function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) performs the recode operation, producing the Worker IDs that correspond to the Worker names.

```
df['Owner ID'] = df['Referral Partners'].str.extract('(Org\W\d{1,})',expand=False).map(org_owners)
```

This will result in the dataframe below.

```
    Case Reason     Referral Partners   Owner ID
0   Case reason 1   Org 1               ID 1
1   Case reason 1   Org 2363            NaN
2   Case reason 8   Org 1**Partners     ID 1
3   Case reason 4   Org 100             NaN
```

You can now simply give a path to [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to save the dataframe as an excel file.

```
df.to_excel('/path/to/excel_file.xlsx')
```